# Displaying latex equation in gitlab wiki using the markdown editor

Tags: markdown, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am interested in building a wiki for my scientific computing code on gitlab which needs me to write equations and render them in the wiki in gitlab.

How to do this.
I tried to paste the mathjax rendering script but it doesn't work.

Can KaTeX be used anyhow ?

```
$$
  \partial_t \int_{\Omega} \mathbf{q} d \Omega =
  \int_{\partial \Omega} \mathbf{f} (
  \mathbf{q}) \cdot \mathbf{n}d \partial
  \Omega - \int_{\Omega} hg \nabla z_b
$$
```

Comment: http://superuser.com ?

Comment: @user3159253 Well the above is a latex equation code snipped that I need to render on the gitlab wiki but the markdown is not able to render the equation. In fact what gets rendered is the text snippet as it is.

Comment: Well, it's nothing wrong with the question. But it seems it's suitable for a different site because it's not about programming or even programming tools, right?

Comment: @user3159253 thanks, what I am looking for is a way to write equations in markdown language (both gitlab and github uses the markdown language for readme and wiki). So I guess it's about programming and hence I have tagged markdown, git and gitlab based community.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

GitLab supports KaTex from GitLab CE 8.15 using code backticks.

Documentation is [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/user/markdown.md#math) and the 
Relevant discussion are on [merge request 8003](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/8003).

Here is the current way to use equations in GitLab

[image: Syntax]
[image: Preview]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not compatible with external markdown editors and only renders correctly in Gitlab. Which causes problems. Which also started the discussion about a change. As of today, it has not changed tho.

Answer (score 3):

**Update Feb. 2017**: as documented in [sfarzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3451554/sfarzy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42081405/6309), this is now integrated ([merge request 8003](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/8003))

---

**Original answer, Feb. 2016**: Regarding Mathjax, there was a [ticket requesting its integration in 2014](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-deprecated-feedback-forum/suggestions/4201014-enable-mathjax-support-in-the-gollum-wikis) (also [PR 5280](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/5280))

If you have access to your own gitlab server, you [could integrate Mathjax yourself](http://nd.psychstat.org/blog/integrate_mathjax_with_gitlab) (source [Zhiyong Johnny Zhang](http://nd.psychstat.org/research/johnny_zhang))

> Create the file `/home/git/gitlab/app/views/layouts/_mathjax.html.haml`, e.g.,

```
sudo -u git nano /home/git/gitlab/app/views/layouts/_mathjax.html.haml
```

> with the following content:

```
:javascript
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML');
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

> Then edit the file `_head.html.haml` and change to the following (the first line already existed and the second line was newly added:

```
= render 'layouts/piwik' if extra_config.has_key?('piwik_url') && extra_config.has_key?('piwik_site_id')
= render 'layouts/mathjax'
```

But if you want to publish it on gitlab.com, this integration is not yet active.