# How to color text in Markdown/GitLab

Tags: gitlab, markdown

I'm trying color text in markdown. In editor preview all looks good, but when I push it to a GitLab repository the text is not colored. How can I color text?

```html
In his beard lived three <span style="color:red">cardinals</span>.
```

[image]

Comment: The only colors I can think of which is supported by gitlab is inline diffs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#inline-diff

Answer (score 26):

You could try this it seems that Gitlab renders it pretty nice, hope it helps:

```
$`\textcolor{red}{\text{your text}}`$ 
$`\textcolor{blue}{\text{your text}}`$ 
$`\textcolor{green}{\text{your text}}`$
```

Also there's `diff` fence:

````
```diff
- RED text
+ GREEN text
! ORANGE text
# GRAY text
```
````

[image]

Comment: First syntax doesn't work. In preview i see colors but when i push files to repository colors not works. Second syntax created colored border around text. It is not exactly what I want.

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/8MjTIA8.png">

Comment: hmmm what it renders for the first one, I mean gitlab web renders them at my end. Check update above

Comment: Unfortuntately, this changes the font-family.

Comment: Brilliant, make use of katex math syntax! If you want to change the background color see https://katex.org/docs/migration.html#cfrac-color-textcolor-colorbox-fcolorbox.

Comment: The first syntax does not work.
The second syntax works but orange shows up as bold gray.
screenshot here: https://i.imgur.com/NzKYLFi.png

Comment: As pointed out by @yancyn , the first syntax is LaTeX formatting. I made an example snippet here: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/3606132
It works when KaTeX is installed and enabled, which it is on gitlab.com. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42081405/776953. Because it's LaTeX, it uses the LaTeX font. If you want to match GitLab's Markdown font, set the LaTeX font with `\sf` or `\textsf`. See https://katex.org/docs/supported.html#style-color-size-and-font

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately most of the HTML hacks for doing color in Markdown will be nullified by GitLab's presentation layer.

GitLab's [inline diffs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#inline-diff) will work for Markdown displayed by GitLab in Issues, Wikis, and by the Markdown Preview.

It supports `[- red text -]` and `[+ green text +]` but no others.  Besides its intended purpose, this is useful for highlighting in Markdown documentation and comments because it is the background that is shaded, not the lettering.

---

As answered by @dejanualex, you can also use [inline LaTeX](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#math) (the documentation does not render the LaTeX, so this is better viewed in [the docs code on GitLab itself](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/user/markdown.md#math)). I made an example snippet here: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/3606132

[image]

It works when KaTeX is installed and enabled, which it is on gitlab.com. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42081405/776953.

Because it's LaTeX, it uses the LaTeX font. If you want to match GitLab's Markdown font, set the LaTeX font with `\sf` or `\textsf`. See https://katex.org/docs/supported.html#style-color-size-and-font